# Ride wasn't canceled

Tags: uber-api

I experienced issue in Uber rides API. Basically what happened was that the ride cancel endpoint returned 204 success response, but ride wasn't canceled.

This was first request:

```
curl -XDELETE -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
 -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8'
```

After that I received webhooks with ride canceled status and receipt ready:

```
{"event_id": "fbba171c-11b9-4081-b473-51ca19c35ceb", "resource_href": "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8/receipt", "meta": {"status": "ready", "rider_id": "xxx", "user_id": "xxx", "resource_id": "45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8"}, "event_type": "requests.receipt_ready", "event_time": 1512401098}



{"event_id": "30d9efaa-f8eb-40f8-a0bd-7bf91ea4f7e3", "resource_href": "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8", "meta": {"status": "rider_canceled", "rider_id": "xxx", "user_id": "xxx", "resource_id": "45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8"}, "event_type": "requests.status_changed", "event_time": 1512401098}
```

But when I asked about status later, returned response said that the status of ride is `accepted`:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  'https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8'

{"status":"accepted","product_id":"b8e5c464-5de2-4539-a35a-986d6e58f186","destination":{"latitude":40.783062,"eta":4,"longitude":-73.97125},"driver":{"phone_number":"(555)555-5555","rating":4.9,"picture_url":"https:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/uberex-sandbox\/images\/driver.jpg","name":"John","sms_number":null},"pickup":{"latitude":40.759068,"eta":1,"longitude":-73.98496},"request_id":"45546b81-cea5-4406-bde6-b574796606b8","location":{"latitude":40.75898,"bearing":null,"longitude":-73.98478},"vehicle":{"make":"Toyota","picture_url":"https:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/uberex-sandbox\/images\/prius.jpg","model":"Prius","license_plate":"UBER-PLATE"},"shared":false}
```

When I send cancel request again, it worked. What happened here?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info - we will try to identify the problem and get back with more info what happens in this case. Initial ride request should be canceled with first delete trigger.

Comment: @SasaJovanovic did you managed to check this issue?

Comment: I managed to identify problematic request in our logs. Our team is looking for the reason why this happens. Looks like it is once off case on our sandbox environment. It is however low priority and there is no ETA when we going to get additional info about this question. If you by any chance run to more cases like this one - please update your question - and this can speed up the resolution.